# Why I obtain this syntax error tryig to concatenate the content of $data['email'] into this e-mail content message?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I am not so into PHP and I have some problem with this code snippet that should represent an e-mail that I will send:

```
$token = md5(uniqid($data['email'], true));

DB::insert('insert into pm_user(firstname, lastname, email, login, pass, type, token) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
            [$data['name'], $data['surname'], $data['login'], $data['email'], md5($data['pass']), 'hotel', $token]);


$registrationMail = [
     'title' => 'Registrazione albergatore su portale BeTrivius',
     'content' => "<p>Hi,<br>You created a new account.<br>
            Click on the link bellow to validate your account:<br>
            <a href=\".getUrl().\"?token=\".$token.\"&email=\".$data['email'].\">Validate my new account</a></p>\";
]
```

The problem is that PhpStorm sign me error on the **$data['email']** variable into the **content** section of the message. Passing the mouse on this variable it says:

> Cannot use [] for reading

So what is the problem? How can I correctly concatenate the content of **$data['email']** variable in my e-mail message content?

Comment: `...email=\"".$data['email']."\">...`

Comment: how do you initialize $data variable? did you try var_dump on it?

Comment: or `...email=\"{$data['email']}\">...`

Comment: similar problem here `...href=\".getUrl().\"?tok...` -> should be  `..href=\"".getUrl()."?tok..`

Comment: aside to Jeff answer, there should not be a `"` at the end of the expression inside an array declaration, the string is not ended

Comment: read about string concatanation, quotes, and escaping quotes.

Comment: PhpStorm is correct here -- the string is **very** messy ad hard to read + it is simply invalid (you have lost `"` somewhere in between). Try rewriting it from scratch. Preferably (for easier editing) using HEREDOC syntax

Comment: @LazyOne HEREDOC would make this worse, not better. Switch to single quotes `'` for your string delimiters and stop escaping the double quotes `"`. There's too much escaping going on

Comment: @Machavity I see now that he uses `getUrl()` which seems to be ordinary function. With that in mind HEREDOC will indeed not help here.